# Unexpected value 'DecoratorFactory' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

This is my spec file:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';
import { ScorecardComponent } from './scorecard.component';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

describe('ScorecardComponent', () => {

  let comp:    ScorecardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ScorecardComponent>;
  let de:      DebugElement;
  let el:      HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ScorecardComponent ],
      imports: [ Component, HttpModule ],  
      providers: [ DataService ]  
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ScorecardComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(comp).toBeTruthy();
  });


});
```

I am getting this error:

> Unexpected value 'DecoratorFactory' imported by the module
>   'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: Remove `Component` from imports array

Comment: if I remove Component from imports array I got below error-

Comment: Remove it here `imports: [ Component, HttpModule ],  `

Comment: if I remove Component from imports array I got below error- failed: Template Parse errors:There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbDropdown"

Comment: Import `NgbDropdownModule`  instead

Comment: Thank You it helps

Comment: Please share if the resolution worked for you. I am also getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

if you have used NgModule and missing NgModule to import we expect such kind a error. 
So please make sure to import NgModule if you are using it: `"import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';"`